# Google Sheets: Fill series with cell references

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I want to fill cells B2:D148 with `=VLOOKUP(Sheet8!B2, Descriptions!A3:B, 2, FALSE)`, replacing `B2` in the formula with the current cell. If I use that formula for B2, then series-fill to C2, I get `=VLOOKUP(Sheet8!C2, Descriptions!B3:C, 2, FALSE)`. C2 updates successfully, but it also increments the lookup range, which should be static.

If I manually fix C2 and D2, then series-fill down to Row 3, it's closer, but the A3 reference still becomes A4, which doesn't work.

Is there any way to series-fill one reference in a formula but not the other?

Alternately, is there any way to reference "this" cell, something like `=VLOOKUP(Sheet8!$THIS_CELL, Descriptions!A3:B, 2, FALSE)`? If so, I could just copy that formula to the entire range.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you wrap your VLOOKUP in an ARRAYFORMULA() ?
In B2, try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(Sheet8!B2:D148, Descriptions!A3:B, 2, FALSE)
```

NOTE: you will have to make sure there are no othere values or formulas present in the range D2:D148

Comment: Well, to answer the question directly, why don't I use it? Because I've never heard of it! :D But that worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I thought I edited my comment. Anyway, is there a way to suppress the "#N/A" that appears in cells with no value in Sheet8?

Comment: Nm, Google helped. Wrapped it in IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(...);;VLOOKUP(...))